# How to create a boolean variable determining if the price of day i is bigger or smaller than the day (i-1)?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new in python.

I tried to create a new boolean variable in my dataset that return down if the price of day i is smaller than the price of day (i-1), and return up otherwise.

```
df['bool'] = ''
for i in range(len(df)):
 if df.iloc[i,10] >= df.iloc[i+1,10]:
     df['bool'].append("Down")
 else:
     df['bool'].append("Up")
```

(10 is the column which contains the prices).

It returns this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-b7a9552986fd> in <module>
  4         df['bool'].append("Down")
  5     else:
 ----> 6         df['bool'].append("Up")

 ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in append(self, to_append, 
 ignore_index, verify_integrity)
   2699             raise TypeError(msg)
   2700         return concat(
 -> 2701             to_concat, ignore_index=ignore_index, verify_integrity=verify_integrity
   2702         )
   2703 

  ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, 
  join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
  282         verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
  283         copy=copy,
  --> 284         sort=sort,
  285     )
  286 

  ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in __init__(self, objs, 
  axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
  357                     "only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"
  358                 )
  --> 359                 raise TypeError(msg)
  360 
  361             # consolidate

  TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are 
  valid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `df['bool'].append("Down")` use `df['bool'] = "Down"` since you have initialized it as a string and not an array.

Answer (score 0):

i think the error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are 
  valid
```

is saying that you can't link strings together in a chain and only series and dataframe object can be concatenated.